# SQL Transaction Rollback Still Return Output Variable Value

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a SQL Stored Proc with an encapsulating transaction and an error is happening inside the SP somewhere, but I cannot tell where. I am trying to use a `@Step` variable to track where the error happens, but it is not working. Essentially, this is what I have:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  dbo.[DoThings]
    @id int,
    @Success char(1) OUTPUT,
    @Step varchar(200) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    Begin Transaction
    begin try 

        set @Step = '101'

                -- do some stuff here

            set @Step = '102'   

            -- do other stuff here

            set @Step = '103'   

            -- do final stuff here

        set @Success = '1'

    commit transaction
    end try 
    begin catch
        rollback transaction
        --if there was an error, return 0 as the Success return value
        set @Success = '0'
    end catch
END
```

and when i run

```
declare @success as bit
declare @step varchar(200)
exec dbo.[DoThings] 81, @success, @step

select @success, @step
```

There is an error somewhere in the logic and I get `null, null` returned.

Am I missing something? I was under the impression that the output variables should still be returned, even if the transaction is still rolled back.

Is there a way I can get the output variables, even after the transaction is rolled back?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to specific OUTPUT for output variables. e.g. `exec dbo.dothings 81, @success OUTPUT, @step OUTPUT`

Comment: DUH! Thank you so much :) that did the trick. If you submit as an answer, I will be happy to mark as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specific OUTPUT for output variables. e.g. `exec dbo.dothings 81, @success OUTPUT, @step OUTPUT`

*Taken from ZLK comment above:*